# Download progress disappears when recycler view binds item again

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-asynctask, android-room

I'm trying to build music player.
`MainActivity` has a `BottomNavigationView` connected with 3 `Fragments` and shares a common `ViewModel` for these 3 fragments and even for the `MainActivity`.
In one of my fragments, I have a `RecyclerView` which shows every song from `RoomDatabase`.

Now when I click on the download button which is on the song, in the adapter I'm making `ProgressView` visible. And it disappears when I move to another `Fragment` and came back to the same `Fragment`.

```
public class HomeRecyclerAdapter extends PagedListAdapter<Song, HomeRecyclerAdapter.SongViewHolder> {
.
.
.
    public class SongViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

        LayoutSongViewBinding binding;
        public SongViewHolder(@NonNull LayoutSongViewBinding binding) {
            super(binding.getRoot());
            this.binding = binding;
        }

        public void bindTo(Song song) {
            binding.setSong(song);

            binding.download.setOnClickListener(view -> {
                if(!song.isDownloaded()) downloadSong(song, binding);
            });

        }
    }

    public void downloadSong(Song song, LayoutSongViewBinding binding) {

        binding.downloadProgress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        DownloadSong downloadSong = new DownloadSong(song, new DownloadCallBack() {
            @Override
            public void onCompleteListener(String path) {
                song.setDownloaded(true);
                song.setSongPath(path);
                viewModel.update(song);

                binding.downloadProgress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

            @Override
            public void onProgressUpdate(int progress) {
                binding.downloadProgress.setProgress(progress);
            }
        });

        downloadSong.execute();
    }

}
```

DownloadTask is AsyncTask which takes two arguments.

Comment: You should add a `downloading` state as a `boolean` to your model and modify the `ProgressBar`'s visibility state according to the this variable. I guess the adapter is recreating the views and that's why it disappears.

Comment: Should I store even progress in the model?

Comment: This is your choice. But event if you don't store the progress, since the download progress is updating frequently, it takes less than a second to update.

Comment: But I want to show an updated progress also. Thank you!!